# Ubuntu Software Center can't install software

Tags: package-management, software-center

Ubuntu Software Center gives me a message:

new software can't be installed because there's a problem with the old software

When I click on Repair, the details are: It requires installation of:

```
gcc-5-base:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed4:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0 libkrb5support0:i386 liblzma5:i386 libnettle6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng12-0 libpng12-0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

pretty much does not install it when I try.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install?

Comment: These are 32bit packages, are you on a 32bit system ? If not run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` then `sudo apt-get -f install`, is it fixed ?

Comment: Also, I read your profile, are you still using 13.10 like you say in other questions ? That would be why you can't install the packages, 13.10 is end of life, the repos are off line, you can't use software center with it anymore. http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: @mondjunge I get the message when I open up the Software Center, even without trying to install anything. Fyi, I was trying to install Virtual Box.

Comment: @markkirby Thank you so much. That worked like a charm.

I'm currently working on 15.10 64-bit system.